# Syntax error in dynamic SQL string

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access, vba

Please help to fix the following syntax error with `Like` statement.  The query works with `=` but I need to use `Like` to search in the AAchange field. I think the problem is here `"WHERE [AAchange] LIKE '" & "%" & _`
 but I'm not sure how to correct this syntax. Please see the code below:

```vb
Sub ColorNewVariant()

Dim PolicyNum As Variant
Dim bFound As Boolean

Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection 'dim the ADO collection class
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset 'dim the ADO recordset class
Dim dbPath As String
Dim strSQL As String
Dim r As Range, cell As Range
Dim LastRow As Long

LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Application.EnableEvents = False

Set r = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("G3:G" & LastRow)
For Each cell In r
        If cell.Value <> "" Then

            PolicyNum = cell.Value

            dbPath = PATH_MAIN & "\Report\MDL_IonTorrent.accdb"

            Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection ' Initialise the collection class variable

            'Connection class is equipped with a -method- Named Open
            '--4 aguments-- ConnectionString, UserID, Password, Options
            'ConnectionString formula--Key1=Value1;Key2=Value2;Key_n=Value_n;
            cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & dbPath

            strSQL = "SELECT [AAchange] " & _
            "FROM [MDL_Table1] " & _
            "WHERE [AAchange] LIKE '" & "%" & _
            Replace(PolicyNum, """", """""", , , vbTextCompare) & _
            """"

            'Create the ADODB recordset object.
            Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset 'assign memory to the recordset

            'ConnectionString Open '--5 aguments--
            'Source, ActiveConnection, CursorType, LockType, Options
            rs.Open strSQL, cnn

            bFound = Not rs.EOF

            'Check if the recordset is empty.

            'Close the recordet and the connection.
            rs.Close
            cnn.Close
            'clear memory
            Set rs = Nothing
            Set cnn = Nothing
            'Enable the screen.

            If bFound Then
            'MsgBox "Record exists."

            Else
            'MsgBox "Record not found."
            'cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 8
            cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 217, 218)
            'cell.ClearComments
            'cell.AddComment "New Variant"
    'Fits shape around text
            'cell.Comment.Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True
            End If

End If
    Next cell

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: In what way is your code not working? I'd suggest to start with you are missing a closing quote `'` after your `Replace` function.

Comment: I get a run-time error at `[AAchange] LIKE '"

Comment: please be specific where to put this missing quote, there are just too many and it's very confusing. Thanks

Comment: What is the error and what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Please add `Debug.Print strSQL` to your code, run it, and then show use the SQL statement text which triggers that error.

Comment: I can't be specific if I don't know what the intention is of your code. I'd suggest declaring and manipulating your string prior to using it in the statement to make your code more readable and easier to debug.

Comment: this is the output in the immediate window  `SELECT [AAchange] FROM [MDL_Table1] WHERE [AAchange] LIKE '%I391M"`

Comment: `LIKE '%I391M"` is wrong.  You need the same type of quote to start and end a string ... either of these should work: `LIKE '%I391M'` or `LIKE "%I391M"`

Comment: @Jeeped  Access expects ANSI wild cards with queries run from ADO/OleDb:  `%` and `_` instead of `*` and `?`

Comment: @HansUp - Thanks! Good to know.

Comment: I've used `SQLwhere = SQLwhere & "[MDL_Table1].[RunName] LIKE '" & "%" & var1 & "%" & "' AND "` in access and it worked fine.. I think the problem is with quotes but I don't know how to fix them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the quoting in your query's `WHERE` clause.

If you use single quotes to start and end the string value you build, you needn't bother with `Replace()` of double quotes within the `PolicyNum` value.  That should make this task simpler and less confusing ...

```vb
strSQL = "SELECT [AAchange] " & _
    "FROM [MDL_Table1] " & _
    "WHERE [AAchange] LIKE '%" & PolicyNum & "'"
Debug.Print strSQL
```

Comment: If there is still a problem, show us the output from `Debug.Print strSQL` and the full text of the error message.  Good luck.

Comment: I don't need `vbTextCompare`?

Comment: You were using `vbTextCompare` as an argument in `Replace()`.  If you don't use `Replace()`, you don't need `vbTextCompare`.  Or have I misunderstood what you're asking?

Comment: it is strange it's finding some of the records but not all.  I opened Access so I know that they exists...but they are colored red in Excel. Thanks

Comment: What happens if you take that SQL text, paste it into SQL View of a new query in the Access query designer, change `LIKE` to `ALIKE` and run it?  Does Access show you the rows you expect?